# Constant functions in a Sobolev hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  be open, bounded, and connected. If $f\in \overline{C_{c}^{\infty}(U)}$ is constant ( in the $||.||_{W^{1,2}(U)}$ norm ) then $f\equiv 0$.

My attempt:

Choose a sequence of test functions $\phi_{n}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$ such that $\phi_n\rightarrow f$ . So, $||\phi_{n}-f||_{W^{1,2}(U)}$ $=(\int |\phi_n -f|^2+|\partial_1(\phi_n-f)|^2)^{1/2}\rightarrow 0$ I'm not sure how to show $f$ must then be 0

Comment: Do you know Poincaré's inequality?

Comment: @Meowdog Yes, but this was used in the proof of Poincare's inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivially extend the sequence $\phi_n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then let $x \in U$: Choose $z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(z, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n) \notin U$ (works since $U$ is bounded).
$$
\lvert \phi_n(x) \rvert^2 = \left \lvert \underbrace{\phi_n(z, x_2, ..., x_n)}_{=0} + \int^{x_1}_z \partial_1 \phi_n(s, x_2, ..., x_n)~\mathrm{d}s\right \rvert^2 = 
\left \lvert \int^{x_1}_z \partial_1 \phi_n(s, x_2, ..., x_n)~\mathrm{d}s\right \rvert^2 
$$
Use Hölder:
$$
\left \lvert \int^{x_1}_z \partial_1 \phi_n(s, x_2, ..., x_n)~\mathrm{d}s\right \rvert^2  \leq \lvert x_1 - z \rvert \int^{x_1}_z \lvert \partial_1 \phi_n(s, x_2, ..., x_n)\rvert^2~\mathrm{d}s \leq C \int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert \partial_1 \phi_n(s, x_2, ..., x_n)\rvert^2~\mathrm{d}s
$$
We had set $C:= \displaystyle \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}: (y_1, x_2, ..., x_n) \in U} \lvert y - z \rvert$. This is finite, since $U$ is bounded.

So we proved:
$$
\lvert \phi_n(x) \rvert^2 \leq C \int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert \partial_1 \phi_n(s, x_2, ..., x_n)\rvert^2~\mathrm{d}s
$$
Then integrate over $(y_2, ..., y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \lvert \phi_n(x_1, y_2, ..., y_n) \rvert^2~\mathrm{d}(y_2, ..., y_n) \leq C\int_U \lvert \partial_1 \phi_n(y)\rvert^2~\mathrm{d}y
$$
Integrate again over $\Gamma := \lbrace y \in \mathbb{R}: \exists (y_2, ..., y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \text{ s.t. } (y, y_2, ..., y_n) \in U\rbrace$ and you have
$$
\int_{U} \lvert \phi_n(y) \rvert^2~\mathrm{d}y \leq C\lvert \Gamma \rvert \int_U \lvert \partial_1 \phi_n(y)\rvert^2~\mathrm{d}y
$$
Then let $n \rightarrow \infty$:
$$
\int_{U} \lvert f \rvert^2~\mathrm{d}y \leq C\lvert \Gamma \rvert \int_U \lvert \partial_1 f\rvert^2~\mathrm{d}y
$$
The derivative is zero and thus $f$ vanishes.

This is basically just another proof of Poincaré's inequality. Little technical, but works.